# Questions about app activities and fragments logic

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabs

I have some questions about Activity and Fragment classes.

So, i have an application that start with a login activity, and then after the login request, leads to a main activity that has a drawer navigation menu (NavigationView). When you click on an item, it loads a Fragment (let's call it FragmentA) inside a RelativeLayout. (to sum it up i'm using what the android studio's activities samples gave me)

The thing i want to do is to add a material design TabView to my toolbar on a few menu's FragmentA, and each tab of that fragmentA will display a new Fragment (FragmentB) that will filter an array of objects (a property of FragmentA), or other stuff.

I was wondering how to do this: what should i use as Fragment A ? Activity or Fragment ? I want FragmentA to still have my NavigationView..

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Child fragments can get added to your fragmentA for this to get done